# Silverlight 4 screenshot OOB

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

Currently I'm trying to do create an out of browser application that captures the whole screen. Not just the Silverlight application.

Now I know that this is not possible with plain Silverlight & C#, but you need to do some dllimports and stuff, it needs to run OOB and you need an elevated application. That is no problem at all.

I found some code on the internet, but I'm stuck. Since Silverlight doesn't have a System.Drawing namespace and thus no [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx). Now I can't cast my GDI+ pointer to something I can display in my Silverlight application.

The code I'm using is from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DesktopCaptureWithMouse.aspx

Can anybody kick me in the right direction? ;)

Comment: What prevents you from using WPF instead of Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is not possible without a lot of hacking with native code.